# Rails 3: Routing Error - uninitialized constant MyController::Google

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using the google-api-client gem (`gem google-api-client, '0.4.1'` in my Gemfile). The following code caused the error `uninitialized constant MyController::Google`:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @client = Google::APIClient.new
  end
end
```

Specifying `::Google::APIClient` didn't help, the error then said `uninitialized constant Google`.

Simply adding a `require 'google/api_client'` at the top of the file made this go away, so it seems there's something wrong in how auto-loading is being done. Not sure what's going on here exactly, specifying the gem in my Gemfile should have automatically required the gem, right? I have restarted the rails server btw.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try adding a `:require => 'google/api_client'` where you specify the google api client gem in the Gemfile

```
gem 'google-api-client', :require => 'google/api_client'
```

This tells bundler that the correct way to require the gem 'google-api-client' is to `require 'google/api_client'`